# Telerik RadPageview Right-to-Left Layout Arrow Keys

Tags: telerik

I have a RadPageview in Strip Mode and I want my program to had support a right-to-left language. When I changing the Right-to-Left Property to true it works fine. but when I run my program and use Arrow Keys (Left or Right) it doesn't work correctly. Left key goes to Right and Right key goes to Left. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik answered my question:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/right-to-left-arrow-keys-problem

the possible solution that I can suggest is to create a custom RadPageViewStripElement and override its IsNextKey and IsPreviousKey methods on a way to reverse the previous/next navigation as follows:

```
public class CustomPageView : RadPageView
{
    public override string ThemeClassName 
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(RadPageView).FullName; 
        }
    }

    protected override RadPageViewElement CreateUI()
    {
        switch (this.ViewMode)
        {
            case PageViewMode.Strip:
                return new CustomRadPageViewStripElement();

            default:
                return base.CreateUI();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomRadPageViewStripElement : RadPageViewStripElement
{
    public CustomRadPageViewStripElement()
    {
    }

    protected override Type ThemeEffectiveType    
    {
        get   
        {
            return typeof(RadPageViewStripElement);    
        }
    }

    protected override bool IsNextKey(Keys key)
    {
        if (this.RightToLeft)
        {
            if (key == Keys.Left)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return base.IsNextKey(key);
    }

    protected override bool IsPreviousKey(Keys key)
    {
        if (this.RightToLeft)
        {
            if (key == Keys.Right)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return base.IsPreviousKey(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it programmatically by using ProcessCmdKey of form.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Right)) 
        {
            int x = radPageView1.Pages.IndexOf(this.radPageView1.SelectedPage) - 1;

            if (x < 0)
                x = radPageView1.Pages.Count() - 1;
            else if (x >= radPageView1.Pages.Count())
                x = 0;

            radPageView1.SelectedPage = radPageView1.Pages[x];
            return true;
        }
        else if(keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            int x = radPageView1.Pages.IndexOf(this.radPageView1.SelectedPage) + 1;

            if (x <= 0)
                x = radPageView1.Pages.Count() - 1;
            else if (x >= radPageView1.Pages.Count())
                x = 0;

            radPageView1.SelectedPage = radPageView1.Pages[x];
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```